# Print only specific matched lines in a file

Tags: ruby, regex

I have input in one file. My input is,

```
Index
chapter 1
    Introduction to ruby
    ruby basics
        Installing ruby
        executing ruby
chapter 2
    Ruby class
    Ruby object
    Ruby method
        Defining method
        Calling method
chapter 3
    Ruby variable
       Local variable
       Class variable
       Global variable
       Instance variable
chapter 4
    .
    .
    .
```

`chapter 1`, `chapter 2`, `3` and `4` etc are headers. I may have n lines in each chapter as sections.

I need to grep the details of a particular chapter. I need all its sections. For example, if I grep `chapter 1`, the output will be,

```
chapter 1
    Introduction to ruby
    ruby basics
        Installing ruby
        executing ruby
```

How do I traverse to the next line, and check for it? Please help me do so.

```
File.open 'test.txt' do |file|
    chap_det=file.find { |line| line =~ /chapter 1:/ }
    puts chap_det
end
```

Comment: Your code sample doesn't read a file. When asking about how to do something it's good to see a bit more earnest attempt to solve the problem. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have successfully read the content into `input` string:

```
input = File.read('test.txt')

chapter = ->(n) { /chapter\s+#{n}.*?(?=\R\w)/im }
#⇒ #<Proc:0x00000002b2d7f0@(pry):59 (lambda)>
input[chapter.(2)]
#⇒ "chapter 2\n    Ruby class\n (...skipped...)  Calling method"
```

The regular expression here matches everything, starting with `chapter N` and ending with carriage return / line feed (any “line break”,) followed by “word symbol.”

```
puts input[chapter.(1)]
# Chapter 1
#     Introduction to ruby
#     ruby basics
#         Installing ruby
#         executing ruby
```

**NB!** The regular expression proposed by Wiktor Stribiżew below in comments is a bit faster, since it does not involve *lazy dot matching*:

```
chapter = ->(n) { /chapter\s+#{n}\b.*(?:\R\B.*)*/i }
```

---

Proof:

```
input = %|Index
Chapter 1
    Introduction to ruby
    ruby basics
        Installing ruby
        executing ruby
chapter 2
    Ruby class
    Ruby object
    Ruby method
        Defining method
        Calling method
chapter 3
    Ruby variable
       Local variable
       Class variable
       Global variable
       Instance variable
Chapter 4
    Introduction to ruby
    ruby basics
        Installing ruby
        executing ruby
chapter 5
    Ruby class
    Ruby object
    Ruby method
        Defining method
        Calling method
chapter 6
    Ruby variable
       Local variable
       Class variable
       Global variable
       Instance variable
|

ch1 = ->(n) { /chapter\s+#{n}.*?(?=\R\w)/im }
ch2 = ->(n) { /chapter\s+#{n}\b.*(?:\R\B.*)*/i }

require 'benchmark'

n = 500000
Benchmark.bm(7) do |x|
  x.report("1:") { n.times do input[ch1.(4)] end }
  x.report("2:") { n.times do input[ch2.(4)] end }
end

#⇒               user     system      total        real
#  1:        6.460000   0.000000   6.460000 (  6.460074)
#  2:        6.010000   0.000000   6.010000 (  6.010000)
```

Comment: I think *ending with carriage return* should be replaced with *ending with a line break* since `\R` matches either `\r\n` or `\r` or `\n`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah, thanks, I am always in doubt on how to call this :)

Comment: plus one .. I really liked your short answer. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if performance can be improved by unrolling `.*?(?=\R\w)` as `/chapter\s+1\b.*(?:\R\B.*)*/i`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think the positive lookahead is even faster, but this is definitely kinda “parse once and forget” task, so one should not probably care.

Comment: You see, in most regex flavors, lazy dot matching patterns are rather expensive, and I believe Oniguruma is not an exception. Compare [`chapter\s+1\b.*?(?=\R\w)`](https://regex101.com/r/cQ1gL7/1) (with a DOTALL modifier) and [`chapter\s+1\b.*(?:\R\B.*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/cQ1gL7/2) (without a DOTALL modifier). If OP text is much larger, that might make a difference.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew indeed, your are right, thanks! I updated an answer and killed one of my fallacies; for unknown reason I thought that positive lookahead takes precedence and state machine basically does the same as for plain `/\R\w/`. Thanks again.

Comment: @mudasobwa I think there is a typo in the benchmark due to which there is about 10X difference between 2 regexes. Actual difference is not that much. Can you check `ch1 = ->(n) { /chapter\s+#{n}.*?(?=\R\w)/im }` and `ch2 = ->(n) { /chapter\s+1\b.*(?:\R\B.*)*/i }`. In second regex you are searching chapter 1 (argument n is not used only) and in first regex you are searching chapter 4. Because chapter 1 is early than chapter 4 - thats why 2nd regex is performing 10x faster. It is fast - somewhat more than marginally . Can you please check ? Thanks :)

Comment: @mudasobwa In my machine the difference was 10.28 sec vs 9.63 sec (regex1 vs regex 2) (if we search chapter **4** in both cases).

Comment: @HarshTrivedi indeed! thank you for checking this out. Fixed.

Comment: @mudasobwa Welcome :) :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew nope; harsh^W picky eye of Harsh Trivedi found a glitch with my benchmark: the execution times could be considered same.

Comment: @mudasobwa I realised it while trying to add my method also in the bechmark and check. I realised not only that my method performs badly in time, but also the small typo in benchmark ! Btw, do you think I should keep my answer or delete it. I don't think its adding much value besides your 2 really awesome answers!

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity: the solution that makes use of [`flip-flop` operation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Flip-Flop):

```
▶ N = 2
▶ File.readlines('text.txt').select do |line|
▷   true if line[/chapter #{N}/i]..line[/chapter #{N+1}/i]  
▷ end[0...-1].join $/  
#⇒ "chapter 2\n  (... skipped out ...)  Calling method"
```

It is ≈3 times slower than regexp solution.

Answer (score 0):

you also can use the following code:

```
chapter_lines = []
start = false
chapter_number = 1
File.open("test.txt", "r").each_line do |line|
    start = true if line["chapter #{chapter_number}"]
    start = false if line["chapter #{chapter_number+1}"]
    chapter_lines << line.strip if start
end    

puts chapter_lines.join("\n")
```

Edit: **Please note** this is assuming that all references to chapter are "chapter" and not "Chapter". In question it's 'Chapter ' once and 'chapter' elsewhere. Difference of small and capital c.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Besides that it is absolutely not idiomatic ruby, I doubt you have it tested.

Comment: You are right. Its not idiomatic at all - atleast it feels so after looking at your answer. But I had started drafting the answer before your answer appeared. So I thought I should keep it.

Comment: But as far as testing is concerned. I have tested it! In the question I guess there is a typo in writing the text file "Chapter 1" and "chapter 2" .. "chapter 3" else where... So I assumed ti to be small 'c'

Comment: @LukasBaliak I already agreed that it's not idiomatic. I didn't it claim to be. But it does solve the purpose. Is the Downvote for style or something else! ?

Comment: @harsh Thank you as you told i have used  'c' and 'C' in elsewhere. I have edited my question. But the format is mismatched while printing the output (tabs and spaces at prefix of every line). That i will check it off. Thank you

Comment: BTW, check my answer with flip-flop operation; it does pretty much the same as yours.

Comment: Yeah I have already upvoted it long back.. Cuz I didn't know something like `flipflops` existed !! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, and Ruby's `slice_before` or `slice_after` methods are useful. Using [`slice_before`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before):

```
doc = <<EOT
Index
chapter 1
    Introduction to ruby
    ruby basics
        Installing ruby
        executing ruby
chapter 2
    Ruby class
    Ruby object
    Ruby method
        Defining method
        Calling method
chapter 3
    Ruby variable
      Local variable
      Class variable
      Global variable
      Instance variable
EOT

chapters = doc.lines.slice_before(/^chapter/).to_a
# => [["Index\n"], ["chapter 1\n", "    Introduction to ruby\n", "    ruby basics\n", "        Installing ruby\n", "        executing ruby\n"], ["chapter 2\n", "    Ruby class\n", "    Ruby object\n", "    Ruby method\n", "        Defining method\n", "        Calling method\n"], ["chapter 3\n", "    Ruby variable\n", "       Local variable\n", "       Class variable\n", "       Global variable\n", "       Instance variable\n"]]

chapters.shift

chapters[0] # => ["chapter 1\n", "    Introduction to ruby\n", "    ruby basics\n", "        Installing ruby\n", "        executing ruby\n"]
```

`chapters.shift` is there to remove the first element resulting in an array of each chapter, indexed in order.

From there it's easy to restore the entire "chapter" content using `join` if you need to, but since the lines are already array elements you'll probably want to keep them as they are:

```
chapters[0].join # => "chapter 1\n    Introduction to ruby\n    ruby basics\n        Installing ruby\n        executing ruby\n"
```

Since you're reading from a file, as long as the file will fit into memory safely, you can use `File.readlines('file_to_read')` to read it and convert it into an array, which you can then use with `slice_...`.